# Nivo: give each slides caption a different class name?

Tags: php, javascript, nivo-slider, caption

I'm using the plugin [Nivo Slider Light](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nivo-slider-light/) and I want to colour the caption backgrounds a different colour per slide.

It's only uses one div called nivo-caption, how can I adjust it slightly to name each div something different so I can target it via CSS?

Comment: Need to edit the js file.

Comment: @JimmyKane Yep with what?

Comment: To enable reading background properties from your elements

Comment: @JimmyKane Sorry to sound like I don't appreciate the comments, but yes, two very obvious statements!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with the Nivo slider, but I came over [this article](http://www.soslignes-ecrivain-public.fr/Nivo-Slider-change-caption-position-for-each-slide.html) that shows how you can position the captions differently.

From what I understand, you can use the same method for applying different colors, and add styles for each `nivo-captionX p`:

```
.nivo-caption1 p {
  background: #7ea5b3;
}

.nivo-caption2 p {
  background: #587580;
}

.nivo-caption3 p {
  background: #557101;
}
```

**Update:**
[This article about styling captions](http://www.soslignes-ecrivain-public.fr/Nivo-Slider-5-new-tips-to-change-its-look.html) might also be helpful.